# How to have an else statement after a loop with an if statement?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a registration system with text files and I need help with using an else statement after the loop that checks if the username is taken.

I am generally just trying to find out how to have an else statement after a loop with an if statement, if I find out that out my problem is basically solved. Here is the code:

```
while($i < count($logindata)-1) {
  if ($_POST['username'] == $user[$i]['username']) {
    set_message(" That username is taken", "danger");
  }
  $i++;
}
else {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        file_put_contents('logininformation.txt', $_POST['username'] . "?=%&$#@[}[}+-789409289746829" . $_POST['password'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        set_message("Account created!", "success");
    } else {
      set_message(" You have not put in a username and/or password","danger");
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to have an else statement after the loop and it working.

Comment: That's not a feature that PHP has, and adding it wouldn't make sense with the nested structure of the language. Having an if statement within a while loop wouldn't allow you to use an else clause, because while loops should always work the same no matter what's inside them. More importantly, when the `if ($_POST['username'] == $user[$i]['username]` statement is run, it doesn't stop the while loop from running, so it wouldn't make sense for the contents of the else clause to run anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop is not a condition, therefore it does not have an `else` part either. It is correct that the loop runs while the condition evaluates to true, but as soon as the condition does not evaluate to true, the loop is ended.

Therefore, to check whether the loop was not triggered at all, you have to find a different way, e.g. write a condition on its own.

For the sake of argument, you `COULD` save a flag and evaluate that afterwards, but in most cases **I would not recommend that**:

```
$i = 0;
$loopDidRun = false;
while ($i < 10) {
    $i++;
    $loopDidRun = true;
}

if (!$loopDidRun) {
    echo "loop did not run, therefore the 'else case', but not really";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It doesn't matter how it's done, just that it has the same outcome as I intended. Thanks for the help, this worked! I'm new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is severely flawed.

```
$failed=false;

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    $failed=true,
    set_message(" You have not put in a username and/or password","danger");
}else{
    while($i<count($logindata)-1){
        if($_POST['username']==$user[$i]['username']){
            $failed=true;
            set_message("That username is taken","danger");
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

if(!$failed){
    file_put_contents('logininformation.txt',$_POST['username']."?=%&$#@[[}+-789409289746829".$_POST['password']."\n",FILE_APPEND);
    set_message("Account created!","success");
}
```

However all I am doing here is fixing bad code. Before anything you need to filter the `$POST` input given to disallow just any input, passwords etc. should not be stored in plain text, and this is not the proper way of creating a factory for this. You should find better, and secure, examples online and work from them.

Comment: I am not trying to create a real site, this is just for learning and for fun. I know that there might be problems with what people input and that text files are not the best method. The answer before solved my problem. I also did not put in the entire code as it was not the part I needed help with.